# Reinstalling macOS Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, filevault

My MacBook won't boot. I did some research online and I realized that this is a common bug. It seems that sometimes the OS starts with a blank screen. [I have tried all sorts of troubleshooting](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-to-fix-mac-wont-turn-on-3423817/) but it still does not work.

My final solution was to reinstall the OS using the Recovery Mode (boot and press the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) but this also, unfortunately, does not work.

When I tried to reinstall the OS via the Recovery Mode, I get an error message that my disk is encrypted by FileVault encryption despite having entered my normal login password.

I also was trying to download a dmg file of macOS Sierra but it seems Apple only allows the file to be downloaded using another Mac computer. This is not possible for me since I do not have access to another Mac.

At this point, I don't know what to do. Can someone give me any suggestions to:

1. Restart normally without the blank screen
2. Reinstall the operating system

Comment: Try Internet Recovery - `Command-Option-R` or `Shift-Command-Option-R` which will reinstall the OS that came with your Mac.  For more details see:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201314

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the Internet recovery but my computer installation is stuck on the Filevault conversion. It says it is paused and i don't know how to go past this stage

Comment: You have to enter your FileValut password which may be different than your login password.  If you don't know it you will need to wipe the disk and start from scratch.

Comment: How do I wipe the entire disk then? I do not remember the password

Comment: BTW, is the FileVault password the same as my password for my icloud password?

Comment: It *could* be - only the person who set the FileValut password would know for sure.  To wipe the disk, boot into Recovery, go into Disk Utilities (top menu) and wipe the drive.